# ByteBuddy: generate a static initializer?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

ByteBuddy provides `LoadedTypeInitializer` but it is not persisted in generated bytecode.

Is it possible to generate a static initialisation block?

```
class Foo { static { /** Added code here **/ } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on the builder:

```
builder.invokeable(isTypeInitializer()).intercept(...)
```

This way you can define it just as any static method.